# Convert bash loop index to floating-point

Tags: shell-script, floating-point

I need to use the index `i` in a loop such as `for i in {0..10..5}` in a floating-point calculation.
What is the simplest way to convert i to floating-point?
Variations on

```
i=$(bc -l <<< "scale=7;$i")
```

do not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `bc` or `awk` or a shell with floating point support like `ksh93`, `zsh` or `yash` instead of `bash`.

### bc

```
$ bc -l << \EOF
heredoc> for (i = 0; i <=  10; i += 2.5) i / 2
heredoc> EOF
0
1.25000000000000000000
2.50000000000000000000
3.75000000000000000000
5.00000000000000000000
```

### awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for (i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2.5) print i / 2}'
0
1.25
2.5
3.75
5
```

### zsh

```
$ float i; for ((i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2.5)) print $((i/2))
0.
1.25
2.5
3.75
5.
```

### ksh93

```
$ for ((i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2.5)); do print "$((i/2))"; done
0
1.25
2
3.75
5
```

(beware the decimal separator is locale dependent (`.` or `,`).

### yash

```
i=0; while [ "$((i <= 10))" -ne 0 ]; do
  echo "$((i / 2))"
  i=$((i + 2.5))
done
```

(inside `$((...))` you use `.` as the decimal separator, but on I/O, the locale's one (`.` or `,`) is used instead).

---

### Edit

now if you just want to loop over some integers and those integers be represented with a decimal point in them, the just append a `.0`:

```
 for i in {0..10..5}.0
```

Or for the solutions above use `printf "%.7f\n"` instead of `print`/`echo` to output the numbers with 7 digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: I'm still looking for something simple. i=$(echo "scale=7; $i/1." | bc -l) works. But why doesn't it work for 0?

Comment: @user94858, that code just adds `.0000000` to the end of your number. 12 and 12.000000 are both text floating point representations of the 12 integer number. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I'm using bash scrips to generate various input files (think of them as text files) for a program. These files must show numbers with decimal points, for floating point calculations in the program.

Comment: @user94858, if they're all integers, then just add `.0`: `i=$i.0`.

Comment: That's simply it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to divide the value by something (even 1) in bc to get the scale to matter:

```
$ i=5; bc -l <<< "scale=7;$i/1"
5.0000000

$  i=5; bc -l <<< "scale=7;$i/2"
2.5000000
```

---

### Edit:

To special case 0 (which doesn't add `.0000000` by default) you could add:

```
$ [ "$i" -eq 0 ] && i="0.0000000"
```

But **beware** that that doesn't make the value a floating-point number, just an string that looks similar to a floating point number.

Also, you could `printf` the needed representation:

```
$ i=3.75
$ i=$( printf "%.7f\n" "$i" )
$ echo "$i"
3.7500000
```

Take into account that bash printf will honor local decimal separator. If it is a comma, you should write `i=3,75` and you will get back the result also with a comma.

---

You will need to change to some other language or some shells to actually use floating-point numbers:

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)    Use a dot for decimal.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { i=5; print( i / 2 ); i=7; print( i / 3 ) }'
2.5
2.33333
```

[ksh93](/questions/tagged/ksh93)  Respect locale settings.

```
$ float i; i=7; print $((i/2)); print $((i/3)); print $((3,7/2))
3,5
2,33333333333333333
1,85
```

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) zsh will use a dot `.` even on locales that use a comma `,`.

```
$ float i; i=7; print $((i/2)); print $((i/3))         ### or typeset -f i
3.5
2.3333333333333335
```

[yash](/questions/tagged/yash)

```
$ echo $(( 7/3 )); echo $(( 7.0/3 ))
2
2,33333333333333

$ i=7; echo $(( i/3 )); i=7,0; echo $(( i/3 ))
2
2,33333333333333
```

Float numbers should be assigned with locale decimal separator.
However, inside `$(( ))` a dot must be used.

Comment: i=$(echo "scale=7; $i/1." | bc -l)  works,but why doesn't it work for zero?